# Python telegram bot via proxy with authentification

Tags: python, proxy, telegram, telegram-bot

everyone.

I am trying to create a simple telegram bot. In my country telegram is blocked so I need to work via proxy.

```
from telegram.ext import Updater         
from telegram.ext import CommandHandler  

import os

def start(bot, update):
    print("Hello")
    bot.sendMessage(chat_id=512562849, text="Hello.")

REQUEST_KWARGS={
    'proxy_url': 'http://93.171.217.48:10996',
    'urllib3_proxy_kwargs': {
    'username': '***',
    'password': '***',
    }
}


updater = Updater(token='<BOT_TOKEN>',
                  request_kwargs=REQUEST_KWARGS)  


start_handler = CommandHandler('start', start)  

updater.dispatcher.add_handler(start_handler)   
updater.start_polling()
```

But I have the next log

```
Exception in thread updater:
...
    _HTTPConnection.__init__(self, *args, **kw)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'username'
```

I used [the next docs](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Working-Behind-a-Proxy).

The free proxy works ok, but for my goals, it's bad to lose connection time after time. I prefer not to work under VPN either because of some bureaucracy in my company.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're using a SOCKS5 proxy. If that's the case, the proxy url protocol should be `socks://` instead of `https://`, in your example:

```
REQUEST_KWARGS={
    'proxy_url': 'socks5://93.171.217.48:10996',
    'urllib3_proxy_kwargs': {
    'username': '***',
    'password': '***',
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just ran the same issue and came up with the following.

1) Make sure we import required function from `urllib3`:

```
from urllib3 import make_headers
```

2) Fill appropriate values:

```
REQUEST_KWARGS = {
    'proxy_url': "http://ip:port",
    'urllib3_proxy_kwargs': {
        'proxy_headers': make_headers(proxy_basic_auth='username:password')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used tor to connect and my problem was fixed.

1. [Download](https://www.torproject.org/download/), install and run the tor browser.
2. Install pysocks dependency. `pip install pysocks`
3. And in the code: `REQUEST_KWARGS = { 'proxy_url': 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9150' }`

Answer (score -1):

I was behind corporate https proxy with auth and I solved with [Working Behind a Proxy](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Working-Behind-a-Proxy) which basically proposes this:

> ```
> TOKEN='YOUR_BOT_TOKEN'
> REQUEST_KWARGS={
>     # "USERNAME:PASSWORD@" is optional, if you need authentication:
>     'proxy_url': 'http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@PROXY_HOST:PROXY_PORT/',
> }
> updater = Updater(TOKEN, request_kwargs=REQUEST_KWARGS)
> ```